# How to make validation update while user types in laravel 8?

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, validation

I'm trying to make validation update while user types with laravel but there is no effect.
How to make validation run dynamically while user is typing. I used bellow form. It shows what I need should i use ajax or what ? it's good if some one help me with simple example.

form:

```
    <form action="{{route('about.store')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <label for="validationServer01">Title</label>
            <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationServer01" placeholder="Title">
            @error('title')
            <div class="valid-feedback">
              {{$message}}
            </div>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <label for="validationServer02">Short description</label>
            <input name="shor_des" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationServer02" placeholder="Short description">
            @error('shor_des')
            <div class="valid-feedback">
              {{$message}}
            </div>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Long Description</label>
            <textarea name="lon_des" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
            @error('lon_des')
            <div class="valid-feedback">
          {{$message}}
            </div>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add about</button>
</form>
```

This is Form validation:

[image]

Request validation:

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'=> 'required',
        'shor_des'=> 'required',
        'lon_des'=> 'required'
    ];
}


public function messages()
{
    return [
        'required' => 'required field'
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
 public function store(AboutRequest $request){
     return $request;
    //return redirect()-> route('about.index')-> with(['success'=> 'save success']);
}
```

what should i do could you help me

Comment: "_should i use ajax or what ?_" Well yes, if you don't want to submit your form first. Or use JS validation _in addition_ to your server-side validation

Comment: You can use AJAX or livewire since it supports realtime validation. laravel-livewire,com for docs

Comment: Could u show by livewire with simple example